# In XNA 2D collision detection, does the Origin of the drawn texture factor in?

Tags: xna, collision

I can't seem to tell if I should be factoring in the Origin of the drawn texture when making a rectangle to do collision (intersects) detection. Most of the examples I have seen make the Origin X/2, Y/2 when drawing but then they do not do anything special when creating a rectangle of the location for detecting collision. I am experimenting with it but have not come to any concrete conclusion especially for small objects. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my own experience, the origin of the quad factors in when considering linear transformations such as scaling and rotation. This can have a direct implication on the bounding square that you generate from the quad as it will effect the bounding square transformations also.

It is important to ensure that they both align so that one transformation maps correctly from one square to the other. So what I would do is ensure that the origin of the bounding square maps to the quad.

Personally, I just use the quads bounding space calculated from the center of the quad and test for AABB collision within those confines. Obviously you need to devise the confines based on how large the object is from the center.

Comment: Just to clarify, if my sprite is 20px wide and my origin is in the center and the position of the sprite is at 10 on the x axis would I offset the bounding rectangle -10px from the location of the sprite? My assumption is that setting the sprite's location to 10 on the X (with a center origin) sets the center of the sprite to 10. Is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: All transformation carried out upon an entity, 3D or 2D are carried out in relation to the local coordinates of that entity. So this means, your transformed quad will result in the origin locating at that point in space specified once the operation is complete.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. My game object has a position of type Vector2D which is a single point (not used for bounds checking, obviously). I must create a Rect (quad?) around the Vector giving top and left for the new Rectangle that depends on origin. In essence, the answer to my question is that I do have to account for origin when making a bounding rectangle. Yes? This is my first game but I have developed software for quite a while. Thanks again.